# cmd + [num] doesn't change screen to go to app in fullscreen mode

Tags: macos, terminal, fullscreen

Consider the situation where I have two spaces screens. From the second screen I open a terminal and make it fullscreen.

By doing so I expected cmd+3 to take me to the terminal app, but it doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do ⌃ → (default) to move one space to the right, which is where your app should be. You can change these settings in the Keyboard preferences:

[image]

An alternate is to use Cmd-Tab to bring up the applications list and navigate.

Comment: yes, but I wanted the [num] option to directly move between say from 1 to 3

Comment: @raja Lion doesn't see it as a numbered space. If you look at Mission control, it shows "Desktop 1", "Desktop 2" and "Terminal"...

Comment: @raja If you check those "Switch to Desktop X" boxes in the screenshot you can go directly to specific spaces by clicking control + space #

Comment: @KyleCronin Yes, but that will take you only to the _numbered_ space. I get the feeling OP knows that, but wants to, say, use ctrl + 3 (when there are only 2 spaces) to go to the first fullscreen app.

Comment: @R.M You're right, I had conflated spaces and full screen apps.

Comment: @R.M, as you guess I indeed want only the number key. To ask my question in a different way: is there a way to make an app fullscreen in the current desktop window? (in this way I can use the number key)

Comment: @raja I understand you, but I don't think it works that way. Numbered spaces are numbered for a reason — you can have certain apps in each and be assured that they'll be in that space when you move to that. On the other hand, you can have multiple fullscreen apps and you can open and close apps or change between fullscreen and window modes and a number is not reliable. You can confirm that the order of the fullscreen app does not influence the shortcut — bring up mission control and manually bring your Terminal app in-between the two spaces and try Ctrl-2. It'll not switch to that app :)